# Добрый день! Я новичок и не могу понять почему код не работает?

Tags: php

Не могу самостоятельно разобраться почему в первом случае код не работает. Припопытке использовать эту функцию и посчитать количество уникальных символов  в $text = "qwew", я получаю "0"?

```
function countUniqChars($text)
    {
        $uniqChars = [];
    
        foreach ($text as $char) {
            if (!in_array($char, $uniqChars)) {
                $uniqChars[] = $char;
               
            }
        }
        return count($uniqChars);
    }
print_r(countUniqChars($text));
```

Во втором варианте функция отлично работает. $text = "qwew", я получаю "3".

```
function countUniqChars($text)
{
    $uniqChars = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i ++) {
        if (!in_array($text[$i], $uniqChars)) {
            $uniqChars[] = $text[$i];
        }
    }
    return count($uniqChars);
}
print_r(countUniqChars($text));
```

Comment: Почему ты решил, что он не работает?

Comment: Твой код работает

Comment: Внес дополнительные комментарии - теперь  надеюсь будет понятней

Comment: @АлександрФедоров дополнил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего нужно над переменной `$text` произвести манипуляцию в виде разбивки на символы **[str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-split.php)** и только потом делать цикл

```
$chars = str_split($text);

foreach ($chars as $char....
```

---

**UPD**

> Во втором варианте функция отлично работает. $text = "qwew", я получаю "3".

Надо понимать, что не смотря на то, что к символу строки можно обратиться через квадратные скобки, как в случае с массивом, сама строка не является массивом (см. **[Документацию по типам данных](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.php)**), это **разные** типы данных. Потому методы работы с массивом не подходят для работы со строками. Нужно применять функции работы со строками, как в примере, что приведён в самом начале. А также итерация в `foreach` происходит один раз и берёт сразу всю строку именно потому, что

> Конструкция `foreach` предоставляет простой способ перебора **массивов**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нравятся мне такие авторы вопросов. Ниче не понятно. Теперь сам придумал проблему, сам ответил. осталось вопросы самим задавать :)

Comment: @splash58 https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/978edcbc07f7135c401f2c41eca01132.jpg  %)))